# Creative Mode - Transport to Nether World And Back Gone Wrong!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My son was in creative mode and went through a Nether Portal to see what it was like and when he went back through the Portal he is in a totally different world (not his own) - is there a way to get back (I don't play this game and have no clue!)

He is frustrated so any help would be appreciated.
Many thanks

Comment: Did he make a new portal in the Nether, or did he go back through the same one?
If he made a new portal, it's possible that he is far enough from his base that he doesn't recognize anything - moving 1 block in the Nether transports you 8 blocks in the Overworld

Comment: He says he went through the exact same portal?

Comment: The chances that he's in a totally different world are slim to nil.  It is entirely possible that he came out of a new overworld portal and is in a different area of his world, though.  The easiest way to get to his starting area is to [respawn](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/117559/1351).

Comment: Thanks - he is in Peaceful Creative Mode so he does't know how to do that as he can't be killed?  I followed the link but it didn't help me much (since I know very little about this game - sorry!)

Comment: Depending on how close you built to the spawn point, you could equip a compass to point you home.

Comment: @Nicky The linked Q/A is all about typing commands but basically you just want the /kill one as he is in creative and his inventory is likely not that important.

Answer (score 8):

An overworld just disappearing like that is *highly* unlikely. If I had to guess, your son created a new portal after exploring the nether, which put him in a completely different part of the same overworld. To get back to spawn, you could try a few things (which are especially easy in creative mode):

- Type `/kill` in the console: You'll die, and respawn where you were when entering the world.
- Type `/tp [playername] 0 70 0`: This will teleport you to the center of the world, a little above ground level.
- Use a compass: If commands aren't at your disposal, you can always just grab a compass and follow it back to spawn.